# Validate multiple fields in rails in the form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have this form in my app, I want to validate couple of fields of the form. I.e. I want to make them as required field during a form submission.

Is there any way so that I don't have to use any gem or any good gem that is straightforward for this particular task?

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :name %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :name, :class=>"form-control", :placeholder=>"Enter Your Name" %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :email %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :email, :class=>"form-control", :placeholder=>"Enter Your Password"%>
      </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :phone %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :phone, :class=>"form-control", :placeholder=>"Enter Your Phone Number"%>
      </div>
   </div> 
</div>

<div class = "col-md-8">
   <div class="form-group">
     <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :description %><br />
      <%= f.text_area :description,  :class=>"form-control", :size=>"20x5", :placeholder=>"Enter Your Message"%>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "Submit", :class=> "button1"%>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: why don't you write validation(e.g.  validates_presence_of, validates_uniqueness_of) codes on your `model`?

Comment: I want the validation on the client side.

Comment: Suraj, are you familiar with javascript and the jQuery library?  If you don't want to use a js plugin, you will need to write your own validations in a js file and have it compile in the asset pipeline on run if you want them to be client side.

Answer (score 0):

We can have various plugins for client side validations.
You can chose jquery_validate for this purpose.
Refer : http://jqueryvalidation.org/

But client side validation is not always reliable. If you disable browser javascript the validation won't work anymore.

**But from user experience point of view, Consider implementing client side validations. But application security point of view you should consider having server side validations as well.**

```
  validates :name, 
    presence: { message: "Organization name is mandatory." }

  validates :address, presence: {message: 'Address is mandatory.'}

  validates :description, presence: { message: 'Description is mandatory'}
  validates_length_of :name, 
    maximum: 50, too_long: "Maximum 50 characters allowed."

  validates_length_of :address, :description, 
    maximum: 300, too_long: "Maximum 300 characters allowed."
```

Hope it helps you :)